# Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The result must not have children

Tags: custom-element

I've been using custom elements v1 for a while now via a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element).  Chrome 54 (the first version with a native v1 implementation) started throwing errors when initializing my elements:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The result must not have children

The offending line is a simple:

```
let el = document.createElement('my-custom-element');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Chrome's native implementation appears to be enforcing specification requirements that the polyfill was not.  According to the "[Requirements for custom element constructors](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance)" section of the spec:

> The element must not gain any attributes or children, as this violates the expectations of consumers who use the createElement or createElementNS methods.

The element that I was attempting to create added children to itself in its constructor.

The solution was to follow the recommendations of the spec:

> In general, work should be deferred to connectedCallback as much as possible—especially work involving fetching resources or rendering. However, note that connectedCallback can be called more than once, so any initialization work that is truly one-time will need a guard to prevent it from running twice.

That is, add children in the connected callback and use a flag to ensure the element is only initialized on first connection.