# DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The result must not have children

Tags: html, custom-element

I am running into the DOM exception (title) and have no clue how to resolve it. This is the same exception from [this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181683/failed-to-execute-createelement-on-document-the-result-must-not-have-childr). As per the solution in the other post, I tried moving the `createElement` call into the `connectedCallback` hook, but I am still seeing the exception.

Simplest code that produces the exception is:

```
connectedCallback() {
    document.createElement('toggle-switch');
}
```

where toggle-switch is a custom element I defined earlier. Any clues as to why this is still happening / how I can get this resolved will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you sure you don't get the old page (from browser cache)?

Answer (score 1):

Oops. Totally my mistake. I did have some DOM manipulation in the constructor of `toggle-switch`. I accidentally added `.innerHTML` on the element instead of it's shadowroot.